# How to shift an array to the left?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

It compiles properly, but when it runs, it prints the array of numbers then a bunch of errors. How could I have the method leftShift shift left?

```
public class ArrayLeftShift {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] myList = {95, -10, 23, -3, 78};

  System.out.print("myList: ");
  printArray(myList);

  leftShift(myList);
  System.out.print("After left shift: ");
  printArray(myList);    
}

public static void leftShift(int[] list) {
 int other = list[list.length+1];

for (int i = list.length+2; i >= 0; i++)
  list[i-1] = list[i];

list[0] = other;
System.out.print("\nshifted Array: ");
}

public static void printArray(int[] list) {
for (int d: list) 
  System.out.print(d + " ");
System.out.println();
}

}
```

Comment: what is the output. what errors are given.

Comment: Your for loop starts at length+2 and runs forever.

Comment: Language tags are important.

Comment: `list[list.length+1];` what do you expect that to do?

Comment: `int i = list.length+2; i >= 0; i++` what do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[] leftShift(int[] a) {
    int[] r = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
        r[i] = a[i+1];
    r[a.length - 1] = a[0];
    return r;
}
```

If you want to shift everything to the left and wrap the first value back to the end this should work....

Answer (score 0):

What is the output you expect to get?

Is it "-10 23 -3 78"?

Or cyclic shift-left "-10 23 -3 78 95"?

I would go with the cyclic and implement like this:

```
public static void leftShift(int[] list) {
  int first = list[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i+1];
  }

  list[list.length - 1] = first;
}
```

Comment: the OP is trying to shift in-place, though